# C# interface method ambiguity

Tags: c#, oop, interface, ambiguity

Consider the following example:

```
interface IBase1
{
   int Percentage { get; set; }
}

interface IBase2
{
   int Percentage { get; set; }
}

interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
}

class AllYourBase : IAllYourBase
{
   int percentage;

   int Percentage {
      get { return percentage; }
      set { percentage = value; }
   }
}

void Foo()
{
   IAllYourBase iayb = new AllYourBase();
   int percentage = iayb.Percentage; // Fails to compile. Ambiguity between 'Percentage' property.
}
```

In the example above, there is ambiguity between which `Percentage` property to call. Assuming the `IBase1` and `IBase2` interfaces may *not* be changed, how would I go about resolving this ambiguity in the cleanest, most preferred way?

### Update

Based on the responses I was getting for using explicit interface implementation, I want to mention that while this does solve the problem it does not solve it in an ideal way for me because I use my `AllYourBase` object as an `IAllYourBase` most of the time, never as an `IBase1` or `IBase2`. This is mostly because `IAllYourBase` also has interface methods (I failed to detail those in my code snippet above because I thought they were irrelevant) that are implemented by `AllYourBase` and I want to access those too. Casting back and forth all the time will get very tedious and result in messy code.

I did try one solution that involved defining the `Percentage` property in `IAllYourBase` and not using explicit interface implementation, which seemed to get rid of the compiler error at least:

```
class IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
   int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a valid solution?

Comment: +1: Interesting problem that IMHO shouldn't exist.

Comment: `base` is not a good name for even a local variable as it can be confused with the `base` keyword which is used to access members of the base class from within a derived class.

Comment: @Jesse it's actually not legal at all. `base` is always a keyword.

Comment: if you can provide more details about what are your classes structure represents here is high possibility that they can be redesigned and you get rid of this problem

Comment: @Jesse: I know it is not valid, it was a contrived example. I didn't even get to compile it. But you get the basic point I'm trying to make...

Comment: You forgot to add the mediator class, "AreBelongToUs"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Implement explicitly:

```
public class AllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
    int IBase1.Percentage { get{ return 12; } }
    int IBase2.Percentage { get{ return 34; } }
}
```

If you do this, you can of course treat your non-ambigous properties just like normal.

```
IAllYourBase ab = new AllYourBase();
ab.SomeValue = 1234;
```

However, if you want to access the percentage prop this will not work (Suppose it did, which value would be expected in return?)

```
int percent = ab.Percentage; // Will not work.
```

you need to specify *which percentage* to return. And this is done by casting to the correct interface:

```
int b1Percent = ((IBase1)ab).Percentage;
```

As you say, you can redefine the properties in the interface:

```
interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
    int B1Percentage{ get; }
    int B2Percentage{ get; }
}

class AllYourBase : IAllYourBase 
{
   public int B1Percentage{ get{ return 12; } }
   public int B2Percentage{ get{ return 34; } }
   IBase1.Percentage { get { return B1Percentage; } }
   IBase2.Percentage { get { return B2Percentage; } }
}
```

Now you have resolved the ambiguity by distinct names instead.

Comment: If I do this, I won't be able access the `Percentage` property in my  `AllYourBase` object as an `IAllYourBase`, correct? This will be a huge negative for me as I primarily use this object as an `IAllYourBase`, not as an `IBase1` or an `IBase2`. One thing I've found that works is to define the interface property yet again in the `IAllYourBase` interface, this seems to resolve the ambiguity as well.

Comment: Great response. This was more than helpful (Although the other responses I upvoted are also helpful).

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you want both properties to access the **percent** member variable you can accomplish this using explicit interface implementation and extending the **IAllYouBase** interface:

```
interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
    new int Percentage { get; set; }
}

class AllYourBase : IAllYourBase
{
   int percentage;

   public int Percentage {
      get { return percentage; }
      set { percentage = value; }
    }

    int IBase1.Percentage {
      get { return percentage; }
      set { percentage = value; }
    }

    int IBase2.Percentage {
      get { return percentage; }
      set { percentage = value; }
   }
}
```

It's not pretty, but it will give you the behavior I think you're after.

Comment: +1 - This is the cleanest solution with the fewest constraints.

Comment: You don't need explicit implementations if both return the same value.

Comment: I didn't even know that you could use the new keyword in an interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Implement the interfaces explicitly.

> An explicit interface member implementation is a method, property, event, or indexer declaration that references a **fully qualified interface member name**

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for a detailed tutorial.

```
interface AllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
   int IBase1.Percentage { get; set; }
   int IBase2.Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an "explicit interface declaration can only be declared in a class or struct" error.

Answer (score 9):

Though you have already accepted the answer. I would argue that explicit implementation asks too much of redundant work (Implementing the same property twice, in your case) !

How about further segregation of interface (Inteface Segregation Principle) ?

```
  internal interface IPercentage
    {
        int Percentage { get; set; }
    }

    internal interface IBase1 : IPercentage
    {
    }

    internal interface IBase2 : IPercentage
    {
    }

    internal interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
    {
    }

    internal class AllYourBase : IAllYourBase
    {
        private int percentage;

        public int Percentage
        {
            get { return percentage; }
            set { percentage = value; }
        }

        void Foo()
        {
            IAllYourBase iayb = new AllYourBase();
            int percentage = iayb.Percentage; // Compiles now!!!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Explicitly implement and access it:

```
interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2 { } 
public class AllYourBase : IAllYourBase
{     
      int IBase1.Percentage { get{ return 12; } }     
      int IBase2.Percentage { get{ return 34; } } 
} 

IAllYourBase base = new AllYourBase();    
int percentageBase1 = (base as IBase1).Percentage;
int percentageBase2 = (base as IBase2).Percentage;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't actually need to return different values for the `Percentage` property, you can eliminate the compiler error by "deriving" from each interface separately, rather than the "master" interface:

```
public class AllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
    // No need to explicitly implement if the value can be the same
    public double Percentage { get { return 12d; } }
}
```

Of course if you *do* need separate values, then you'll have to explicitly implement the interfaces, *and* access the property via an appropriately typed reference:

```
public class AllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
    // No need to explicitly implement if the value can be the same
    public double IBase1.Percentage { get { return 12d; } }
    public double IBase2.Percentage { get { return 34d; } }

}
```

And the code:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    AllYourBase ayb = new AllYourBase();
    IBase1 b1 = ayb
    double p1 = b1.Percentage;

    IBase2 b2 = ayb;
    double p2 = b2.Percentage;
}
```

One important consideration when implementing the interfaces explicitly is that `AllYourBase` itself *no longer has a `Percentage` property*. It can only be accessed when the object is accessed via a reference typed as one of the interfaces:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    AllYourBase ayb = new AllYourBase();
    double d = ayb.Percentage;   // This is not legal
}
```

**UPDATE**: Looking at your edit, your solution is fine, assuming you don't need different behaviour for `IBase1` and `IBase2`. Your solution hides those properties, so they will only be accessible by casting the object to one of those two interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the property in the `IAllYourBase` interface.

Something like this :

```
interface IAllYourBase : IBase1, IBase2
{
   new int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

This will resolve the problems with the ambiguity between the properties. And you can keep the structure of the interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

While explicit implementation the guys have mentioned is obviously correct, please consider following scenarions just for the sake of sanity (or do it just for a person reading your code in the future):

If these percentages have different meanings depending on the interface, why not to give them some meaningful names?

```
interface IBase1 
{ 
    int PercentageBase1 { get; set; } 
}

interface IBase2
{
    int PercentageBase2 { get; set; } 
}
```

And, on the other hand, if they have the same meaning, why not to have just one Percentage in one of the interfaces and just derive one from another?

```
interface IBase1 
{ 
    int Percentage { get; set; } 
}

interface IBase2 : IBase1
{
}
```

However, if the last operation is not possible for whatever the reason is, please consider creating a base interface containing that property for both of them:

```
interface IBase0
{
    int Percentage { get; set; } 
}

interface IBase1 : IBase0
{ 
}

interface IBase2 : IBase0
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void Foo()
{
   IAllYourBase base = new AllYourBase();
   int percentage = base.Percentage; // Fails to compile. Ambiguity between 'Percentage' property.
}
```

In this example you use the `base` keyword for an object name and that may be causing the problem!!!